# How should I be using .setAdapter here? /How do i get around not extending ListActivity?

Tags: android, adapter, listactivity, listadapter

I have a class that is already extending TabActivity so i can't extend ListActivity.

This hasn't be a problem until i needed to use this method:

```
private static int[] TO = { R.id.catItem, R.id.budgetAmount, };
private void showBudgetOutcome(Cursor cursor) {
//Set up data binding 
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
this, R.layout.itemsforbudgetlist, cursor, FROM, TO);
setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Obviously setListAdapter is undefined. Now i found this snippet of code searching SO

```
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
```

But i don't really understand the parameters. I tried altering it to suit me:

```
incomeView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.itemsforbudgetlist, adapter??));
```

I see that mListView is just the users ListView so i replaced that, and the layout resource defining how each item in the list looks i guess. But the rest i'm not sure about. I figure maybe i want a Simple/CursorAdapter since i'm working with sqlite (see my method)? but i have no idea what COUNTRIES is meant to be and not sure what data type i need (presumably string but what do i know). So if someone could clear things up for me and tell me how to use it with my method above i'd be really greatful!

Comment: I can only repeat myself. Get yourself comfortable with the Java basics and then start with Android or at least buy some good Android books. [http://commonsware.com](http://commonsware.com) is a good source and also [Reto Meier's](http://www.amazon.com/Reto-Meier/e/B002BMF4OC/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) books are to mention.

Comment: I know, I am i swear haha. I have a book called "Hello, Android: Introducing Google's Mobile Development Platform" along with some college textbooks and of course the whole of the internet to work from. I'm just having to bulldoze my way through this project a bit because my entry to university relies on it (Long story, but this project makes up 60% of my a-level mark). If i had the time to get that thorough grounding believe me i would, but for now i'm just trying to work things out as they're needed. But thanks again, indispensable advice and i do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pull your data from a database you need to subclass [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).  Then you can just call:

```
incomeView.setAdapter(new MyCursorAdapter(WhatEver arguments, You need));
```

Comment: Ah Thank you very much, But after a bit of fiddling i still can't seem to get it to work with my method above.. are you sure i'm not repeating myself sort of? you see i have something very similar , a SimpleCursorAdapter in showBudgetOutcome.. Sorry i'm new to all this and pretty knackered hah